# Accessing array list from on FXML from another

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a JavaFX GUI and have 2 scenes/windows.

One as the main GUI and a second that shows up when adding a booking.

The booking FXML window uses BookingWindowController.Java which contains the form code and stores the information in an array list like seen below

```
ArrayList<Surgeon> surgeonList;
```

The surgeon class has getter and setter methods as the data fields are private.

I can access this data from the same controller file using

```
String x = surgeonList.get(0).getSpeciality();
```

but this code does not work when trying to access it from my main window controller file (MainPortalController.java) which needs to be able to access the data as it contains my display text area.

Comment: Maybe instead of an ArrayList u should use an ObserveableList. Did you think about using a view model and share it between both controllers?

Comment: A much better solution u can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml from @jewelsea

Comment: It's for a school project and we have to use array lists.

Comment: An `ObservableList` is an `ArrayList`...